# jquery addClass to all labels

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<div id="brand_name">
Audi
<span class="select_all">
Select all
</span>
</div><div class="models">
<label for="search_model_id_in_61"><input id="search_model_id_in_61" name="search[model_id_in][]" type="checkbox" value="61">100</label>
<label for="search_model_id_in_62"><input id="search_model_id_in_62" name="search[model_id_in][]" type="checkbox" value="62">80</label>
</div>
```

I try to write like:

```
$(".select_all").click() {
   var models = $(this).parent().next()
}
```

but how to addClass class="checked" to all labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle between all checkboxes being checked and unchecked, this would work:

```
$(".select_all").click(function() {
    var $select_all = $(this),
        $chk = $select_all.parent().next().find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    $select_all.toggleClass('active');

    if( $select_all.hasClass('active') ) {
        $chk.prop('checked', true);   
    } else {
        $chk.prop('checked', false);     
    }
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/an3jN/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".select_all").click() {
   var models = $(this).parent().next()
   models.find('label').addClass('checked');
}
```

But i'm not sure if checkbox should be inside of `label` tag. I think it should be after or before it.

Answer (score 1):

```
models.children().addClass('checked');
```

or

```
models.children().toggleClass('checked');
```

for class switching.

If you want to check them:

```
models.children('input').attr('checked', true);
```